# Java 9 HttpClient: Correctly handle async response

Tags: java, http, asynchronous, request, java-9

I'm looking to send a request asynchronously and then do something else asynchronously once the response has been received.  So far, the code I have looks like this:

```
httpClient.sendAsync(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandler.asString())
          .thenRunAsync(() -> {});
```

However, I'm not entirely convinced that the `Runnable` will run once the request has completed.  Is this assumption correct? If so, what should I use to handle the response properly once it's received?

Comment: Your assumption is mostly correct: If the HTTP request completes successfully (response code less than 400), your Runnable will run.  Otherwise, the CompletableFuture completes exceptionally, which you can handle with its [exceptionally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#exceptionally-java.util.function.Function-) method.

Comment: Thanks @VGR.  If you want to write an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is mostly correct: If the HTTP request completes successfully (response code less than 400), your Runnable will run. Otherwise, the CompletableFuture completes exceptionally, which you can handle with its [exceptionally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#exceptionally-java.util.function.Function-) method.